# Python multiprocessing.Queue apparently losing data

Tags: python, queue, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to make use of multiprocessing to speed up a program. For this I at some point need to parallelize a task between as many processes as possible, let's say n. Because I don't want to create any more processes than I absolutely have to, I create n-1 new ones, start them, then run the last of the work on the current process and finally join everything together. All of these communicate through a Queue. Each process is passed its 'share of work' by argument, so each of them only needs to put the results on the Queue when they're done (each of these results can be around 6600 5-letter words long).

```
def play(chosen_word):
    l=[chosen_word, chosen_word]
    return l

def partial_test(id, words, queue):
    print(f'Process {id} started and allocated {len(words)} words.')
    guesses=[]
    for word in words:
        guesses.append(play(word))

    print(f"Process {id} has finished ALL WORDS.") #debugging only
    queue.put((id, guesses))
    print(f'Process {id} added results to queue')
    queue.cancel_join_thread()
    print(f'Process {id} closed the queue and exited. Queue has aproximately {queue.qsize()} elements')


def full_test():
    #do stuff

    #create Queue for results
    queue=Queue()

    #initialize auxiliary processes
    processes=[Process(target=partial_test, args=(x, word_list[x*words_per_process:(x+1)*words_per_process], queue)) for x in range(process_count-1)]

    #start processes
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    #run last process on the current thread
    partial_test(process_count-1, word_list[(process_count-1)*words_per_process:], queue)

    #join processes
    i=0
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
        print(f'Joined process {i} with main thread.')
        i+=1

    print("All processes finished!")

    #get results (they need to be in order) 
    results=[[] for _ in range(process_count)]
    i=0
    while not queue.empty():
        res=queue.get()
        results[res[0]]=res[1].copy()
        i+=1
    print(f"Got {i} results!")

    #do stuff with results
```

The problem arises when I try to read the data on the queue. Every process reports that it puts data on the queue, so before the last one joins it has n elements on it. However, when I try to get them and put them in the results list, I only ever pull a single element which contains the data recorded by the n-th process (the one I had running on the main thread).

I initially didn't use queue.cancel_join_thread(), but found that to prevent the processes from joining, even after finishing execution, something about them waiting for a buffer to actually write to the queue, which, in the case of great amounts of data, would not do so until the queue.get() method was called. But since I only get the data once all the processes were finished, that would never be called and the program would get stuck. I suppose it could have something to do with this (though I don't see why it wouldn't affect the n-th process), but I found no way to 'force-flush' the data from the buffer to the queue.

I am also certain that every other function this part of the code might depend on returns the correct data, as I have tested everything on the same data in a single-process version.

Edit: The play function is just a stand-in, but is for all intents and purposes of this post equivalent to the original one, as using this gives the exact same problem. Posting the original one along with all of its dependencies would have meant posting most of my code, which would have made it hard to focus on the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: What is `play`? Maybe for an experiment change things around so that `partial_test`  [pickles](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) its list instead of putting it in a queue - then check if the data you expect is in all those files.

Comment: We cannot test your example because we do not have `word_list` or `play`; you didn't show us how `queue` *was made*, maybe others. Please read [mre] then edit your question.

Comment: Hi, I updated the example for clarity. I have not yet tried pickling to see what that would change, but will do so soon enough. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

So, here's your problem:

> I initially didn't use queue.cancel_join_thread(), but found that to prevent the processes from joining, even after finishing execution, something about them waiting for a buffer to actually write to the queue, which, in the case of great amounts of data, would not do so until the queue.get() method was called. But since I only get the data once all the processes were finished, that would never be called and the program would get stuck. I suppose it could have something to do with this (though I don't see why it wouldn't affect the n-th process), but I found no way to 'force-flush' the data from the buffer to the queue.

With `multiprocessing.Queue`, the reader(s) need to read in parallel with the writer(s) writing. The queue is implemented on top of bounded-size OS-level pipes, and if nothing is reading, writers will quickly fill the pipe's buffer and become unable to write. The errors you were getting were due to that. You didn't find a "force-flush" option because there's nowhere to flush to - the pipe is full, and no one is reading to clear it.

`cancel_join_thread` doesn't solve the problem. By calling `cancel_join_thread`, **you're telling Python, "no, I'm actually totally fine with you throwing away my data"**, so the worker processes happily exit without finishing writing to the pipe, and throw away your data. The documentation [explicitly warns](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.cancel_join_thread) that `cancel_join_thread` should only be used if you don't care about lost data.

---

You could try using a managed queue with `manager = multiprocessing.Manager()` and `queue = manager.Queue()`, since IIRC, managed queues don't have the same limitation, but the way they avoid this limitation involves creating an extra server process to manage the queue, and the whole point of designing your program the way you did was to avoid creating extra processes. Plus, I think manager-based queues have extra inter-process communication overhead.

I would recommend just using `multiprocessing.Queue` the way it was designed to be used - read from it in parallel with the writes. Instead of using the master process as an extra worker, have it start reading data as soon as it's done starting workers, and only join the workers once it's read all data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I reserved the main process for the task of receiving results from the queue and it works properly now!